Is Mutex/Lock required if runing on a single core CPU
I will like to understand why is it unsafe to use unsafe code in rust for accessing a shared resource/varibale in rust if my program runs on a single core computer. ChatGPT and ClaudeAI both say this code is unsafe even if running on a single core computer:
use std::collections::HashMap;

static mut UNSAFE_MAP: Option<HashMap<u32, u32>> = None;

#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    // Initialize map
    unsafe { UNSAFE_MAP = Some(HashMap::new()); }

    let task1 = tokio::spawn(async {
        for i in 0..10_000_000u32 {
            unsafe {
                if let Some(map) = &mut UNSAFE_MAP {
                    map.insert(i, i);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    let task2 = tokio::spawn(async {
        for i in 0..10_000_000u32 {
            unsafe {
                if let Some(map) = &mut UNSAFE_MAP {
                    map.insert(i + 10_000_000, i);
                }
            }
        }
    });    

    // Wait for both tasks
    let _ = tokio::join!(task1, task2);

    // Check final state
    unsafe {
        if let Some(map) = &UNSAFE_MAP {
            println!("Final map size: {}", map.len());
            // Should be 20 million if everything worked
        }
    }
}

I understant that the OS can stop my program at any given time. But once it resumes it should continue running on the same order it was supposed to no? I also undertand that if both tokio threads write to the same file or do any OS related stuff without synchronization/locks there could be problems. I have a single core computer hosted on AWS and I will like to use unsafe code to avoid having locks. I am actually building an RTP server so having no locks will be nice to have. I have run this code for one hour and havent been able to make it fail.
This code is just an example in my real program I plan to have a pointer to a struct that holds all my shared resources. I will be reading most of the time and ocasionally writing to hashmaps. Since I am building an RTP server even if I use a RwLock it takes a long time if I plan on haing 100 concurrent calls.

Edit
And lastly what is safe? for example using a i32 instead of an Atomic32 would be safe on a one single core CPU correct? But a hashmap is not safe correct? So if I never plan on having more than 100 concurrent calls I could use an cicrular array safely? If I have 100 concurrent calls that means I have to send an audio packet every 20 ms and once for each channels so I belive I have a high chance of encountering a contended lock.


I understant that the OS can stop my program at any given time.

It can also change which thread is running at any time. Suppose your Task1 thread is in the middle of inserting a value into the map, and has just chosen a bucket to use and verified that it isn’t full. Then the OS decides to switch to your Task2 thread, which inserts a value into that same bucket. Then the first threat starts running again, and overwrites the value the second thread inserted (because it thought the bucket was still available). In fact, there’s a pretty good chance that something like that is already happening, even if the size (which is tracked separately) appears to be correct.
Thread preemption is more commonly unsafe than process preemption.
Incidentally, grabbing and releasing a non-contended lock, and in particular doing it repeatedly to the same lock on the same core, is very very fast. If you’re seeing slowness in this situation it’s because the lock is contended (as it definitely is here).
P.S. Although they happened to be right here, chat bots like ChatGPT and Claude constantly make mistakes and should never be trusted, even if they claim to cite sources. Don’t ask them things if you don’t already know the answer.

So that means that even if I do not have an await the OS can change the tokio threads? It makes no sense that when the OS allows my rust program to run it does not keep runing on the same order it was running before no? Thanks for the help

I plan on having 100 concurrent calls and they all send audio every 20 ms and also receive audio every 20 ms. Maybe I will not have a free lock but it will be nice if I can just access the shared resource right away so that I do not have audio problems.

What is the shared resource for? What are you sharing? What is the purpose of the map?

on VOIP when I receive a audio packet (RTP packet) each packet has a uniquie id called RRSC. thanks to that id I can map it and see to what endpoint I need to forward that audio packet. The faster I do that the less latency my audio application has. I do not mind having small latency what I mind is having contented locks and when that happens the audio is not clear.

Since the OP uses the current_thread runtime, there are no threads in their code…

Since you're using the current_thread Tokio runtime there are no threads in this code, to this should be safe so long as you don't hold on to a borrow accross await points. The problem is that you can't guarantee that you won't. For example, look at the following code:
unsafe {
    if let Some (map) = &mut UNSAFE_MAP {
        map.insert (1, 1);
    }
}
call_some_async_function().await;
unsafe {
    if let Some (map) = &mut UNSAFE_MAP {
        map.insert (2, 2);
    }
}

Since I'm accessing UNSAFE_MAP from scratch after the await, I should be fine, right? Well no, because the optimizer is allowed to assume that UNSAFE_MAP hasn't changed while the task was awaiting and so it may remove the test for the second if let, or keep a reference to some internal data in the HashMap that it knows will be useful for the second insert. But that assumption may not hold if some other task changed UNSAFE_MAP while we were awaiting.
